# Resizable Batch in Pyglet

Tags: python-3.x, pyglet

I am working in a pyglet application and this app needs to be resizable (resizable = True). So, the problem is: when you resize the window the batch still in the same size.

[image]

[image]

When resize screen, the square stills at the same size...

I need to Batch resize when windows resizes.

Have a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I found, this way, using openGL module (thats pyglet supports)

```
class Window(pyglet.window.Window):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(Window, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.default_width, self.default_height = self.width, self.height

        self.batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()

    def on_resize(self, width, height):

        glMatrixMode(gl.GL_PROJECTION)
        glLoadIdentity()

        glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
        gluOrtho2D(0, self.default_width, 0, self.default_height)
        glMatrixMode(gl.GL_MODELVIEW)
```